# Centering navbar pills vertically within the navbar using flexbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I am terrible at CSS so I am having trouble centering my `<li>` (navbar pills) vertically for my navbar. This navbar is from twitter bootstrap

Here is the HTML for my navbar:

```
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <ul id="nav_pills" class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="/">About</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="/gallery">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="/news">News</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#history">History</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

My navbar currently looks like so:

[image]

I am trying to use `flexbox` as well because while browsing for solutions, using flexbox seems to be an easy way to center my navbar buttons vertically.

This is what I have currently tried but it isn't working =/

```
.nav li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: baseline;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `display: flex` for the `<ul class="nav">`, not for items.
Also use `align-items: center` for vertical aligment:

```css
.nav {
  height: 70px;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <ul id="nav_pills" class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="/">About</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="/gallery">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="/news">News</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#history">History</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To vertically align it, set a line height for the list elements which is equal to the navbar height and remove the top and bottom padding. It won't need `Flexbox` at all :)

```
.nav > li > a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 50px; // Add
    padding: 0 15px; // Modify
    position: relative;
}
```

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/w2ZI8SxNxZ)

Comment: My navbar currently does not have any padding. I changed the height of the navbar and tried your CSS and altered my line-height to be the same height of the navbar. It still centers vertically as if the navbar's line-height hasnt been changed. http://postimg.org/image/hnsv1drv5/   http://dpaste.com/298F5GH